# How to test the anchor tag in react class component using jest and enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, babel-jest

This is my file

```
class Example extends component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state={};
    }
   render() {
      const { url } = props;
        <a href ={url}>
          <div>hello</div>
         </a>
     }
}
```

Test file

```
let props ={url:'www.google.com'};
it("should render  anchor tag and attribute href", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Example {...props} />);
     expect(wrapper.find("a")).toHaveAttribute('href','www.google.com'); //
   });
```

Help me to test href attribute by passing props .
Thanks in advance

Comment: In these situations, it's helpful to explain what error you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you're assigning the whole props object to the `href` attribute of your anchor, and you're not returning anything in the render method.

Try updating your component as follows:

```
class Example extends component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state={};
    }
   render() {
      // Destructure url from props
      const { url } = props;

      // return some JSX
      return (
        <a href ={url}>
          <div>hello</div>
         </a>
       )
     }
}
```

**Update**: Also the matcher should be `toHaveAttribute`. Note the uppercase A.